# Azure Mobile App node.js backend - Cannot get content of request

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I want to use the easy api in Azure mobile app Node.js back-end server.
But I cannot get the content of the request after tried hard.

Can anyone tell me any possible things I lost ?

This is my api (myApi.js):

```js
module.exports = {
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        for (var k in req) {
            console.log("%s: %j", k, req.k);
        }
        res.status(200).send('post');
    }
}
```

This is my app.js:

```js
var express = require('express'),
    azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');

var app = express();

var mobile = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true
});

mobile.tables.import('./tables');

mobile.api.import('./api');

mobile.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
        app.use(mobile);    // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Listen for requests
    });
```

I used Postman to send request.
Postman
[image]

And this is my console log, as you can see, everything of request is undefined.
params: undefined
query: undefined
headers: undefined
url: undefined
statusCode: undefined
body: undefined
...

Comment: remove 'function' after 'then' and try again. just like this: .then(() {
        app.use(mobile);  
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module in your Mobile Apps server, config the body-parser middleware in the mobile app entrance `app.js`. Then you can use `req.body` to get the post body content.

You can try the following steps:

1. Login Kudu console site or Visual Studio Online editor of your mobile app server to modify scripts and run `npm` commands. Add body-parser module like `"body-parser": "^1.13.1"` under `dependencies` section in `package.json` file in your root directory. Run `npm update` to install the dependencies.
2. Add the stmt in `app.js`:

   ```
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));`
   ```
3. Try the code snippet in your Easy APIs:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       "post":function(req,res,next){
           console.log(req.body)
           res.send(req.body)
       }
   };
   ```
4. In Postman, use `x-www-form-urlencoded` to post your data:
   [image]

Comment: Hi GaryLiu
Thanks for your answer, this really resolved my problem.
You did save my time.

Comment: This worked for me.  I think my mistake was I assumed that just because I saw body-parser sitting in node-modules, it was the right version and it was going to work.  I think adding it to package.json and running npm install (for local installs) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log("%s: %j", k, req[k]);` instead.

The reason is variable `k` is a string. Therefore, to access a member by its key as string, you have to use the "array notation"

Comment: Hi JasonWihardja,
Thanks for your answer.
After I tried this, I can see some value of request.
But there is still nothing in request["params"], request["body"], etc.
How can I get the content of request send from Postman ? Thanks.